# Getting digits after decimal point

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm binding an `SqlMoney` type to a `TextBox` in WPF and I'm trying to put digits after decimal point into superscript. This is what I've got so far:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontSize="50">1000</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="TextTop" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="26">00</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Is there a simple way to this in WPF using something like `StringFormat` or I need to split it somewhere else in code and then bind?

Edit:
Ok, I might have explained it badly. This is actual implementation in code right now:

Model property
`public SqlMoney Price { get; }`

View
`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Price}" />`

Effect:
[Effect - before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxXFu.png)

Is there way to make View handle splitting or I need to change implementation in Model or VM?

Comment: You could use stringformat to effectively do the splitting, binding two runs to the number.

Answer (score 1):

When you use binding, you can use `StringFormat` to do what you need. In your example there is no binding so no place for `StringFormat`.

Here is a `StringFormat` you can use when binding:

```
StringFormat={}{0:00.00}
```

Example of binding with `StringFormat` (assuming `Superscript` is a property of you `DataContext`):

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontSize="50">1000</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="TextTop" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding Superscript, StringFormat={}{0:00.00}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

If you don't have yet the `DataContext` set up and you want a self contained example you could create a `Resource` and bind to it:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="Superscript">0</sys:Double>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
    <Run FontSize="50">1000</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="TextTop" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Superscript}, StringFormat={}{0:00.00}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

In this example I had to use `OneWay` binding because I'm binding to a static resource.

Result:

[image]